# Сжатие картинки с сохранением пропорций

Tags: php

Как сделать умное сжатие картинки при загрузке? То есть максимальный размер фото `200x200`, я загружаю `360x500` — фото уменьшается и становится не `200x200`, а, например, `200x179`, чтобы не испортить фотографию.
Можно пример кода загрузки, или ссылку на сам скрипт.

Comment: Если под "умным" вы подразумеваете сохранение пропорций, то почему 360х500 превращается в 200x179? Если подразумевается что-то другое - то что именно?

Comment: примеров нагуглить можно множество, готовые скрипты тут тоже не раздают.  Приведите ваш код для начала. Пропорции, наверное, изучали ведь? Вот и сравните, отношение фактической и желаемой ширины, а также длины. Который коэффициент будет меньше, тот и используйте.

Comment: я нашел.. но он не работает https://php.ru/forum/threads/62342

Answer (score 0):

#### Вот PHP класс как раз вам надо

```
class Picture {

    private $image_file;

    public $image;
    public $image_type;
    public $image_width;
    public $image_height;


    public function __construct($image_file) {
        $this->image_file=$image_file;
        $image_info = getimagesize($this->image_file);
        $this->image_width = $image_info[0];
        $this->image_height = $image_info[1];
        switch($image_info[2]) {
            case 1: $this->image_type = 'gif'; break;//1: IMAGETYPE_GIF
            case 2: $this->image_type = 'jpeg'; break;//2: IMAGETYPE_JPEG
            case 3: $this->image_type = 'png'; break;//3: IMAGETYPE_PNG
            case 4: $this->image_type = 'swf'; break;//4: IMAGETYPE_SWF
            case 5: $this->image_type = 'psd'; break;//5: IMAGETYPE_PSD
            case 6: $this->image_type = 'bmp'; break;//6: IMAGETYPE_BMP
            case 7: $this->image_type = 'tiffi'; break;//7: IMAGETYPE_TIFF_II (порядок байт intel)
            case 8: $this->image_type = 'tiffm'; break;//8: IMAGETYPE_TIFF_MM (порядок байт motorola)
            case 9: $this->image_type = 'jpc'; break;//9: IMAGETYPE_JPC
            case 10: $this->image_type = 'jp2'; break;//10: IMAGETYPE_JP2
            case 11: $this->image_type = 'jpx'; break;//11: IMAGETYPE_JPX
            case 12: $this->image_type = 'jb2'; break;//12: IMAGETYPE_JB2
            case 13: $this->image_type = 'swc'; break;//13: IMAGETYPE_SWC
            case 14: $this->image_type = 'iff'; break;//14: IMAGETYPE_IFF
            case 15: $this->image_type = 'wbmp'; break;//15: IMAGETYPE_WBMP
            case 16: $this->image_type = 'xbm'; break;//16: IMAGETYPE_XBM
            case 17: $this->image_type = 'ico'; break;//17: IMAGETYPE_ICO
            default: $this->image_type = ''; break;
        }
        $this->fotoimage();
    }

    private function fotoimage() {
        switch($this->image_type) {
            case 'gif': $this->image = imagecreatefromgif($this->image_file); break;
            case 'jpeg': $this->image = imagecreatefromjpeg($this->image_file); break;
            case 'png': $this->image = imagecreatefrompng($this->image_file); break;
        }
    }

    public function autoimageresize($new_w, $new_h) {
        $difference_w = 0;
        $difference_h = 0;
        if($this->image_width image_height imageresize($this->image_width, $this->image_height);
        }
        else {
            if($this->image_width > $new_w) {
                $difference_w = $this->image_width - $new_w;
            }
            if($this->image_height > $new_h) {
                $difference_h = $this->image_height - $new_h;
            }
            if($difference_w > $difference_h) {
                $this->imageresizewidth($new_w);
            }
            elseif($difference_w imageresizeheight($new_h);
            }
            else {
                $this->imageresize($new_w, $new_h);
            }
        }
    }

    public function percentimagereduce($percent) {
        $new_w = $this->image_width * $percent / 100;
        $new_h = $this->image_height * $percent / 100;
        $this->imageresize($new_w, $new_h);
    }

    public function imageresizewidth($new_w) {
        $new_h = $this->image_height * ($new_w / $this->image_width);
        $this->imageresize($new_w, $new_h);
    }

    public function imageresizeheight($new_h) {
        $new_w = $this->image_width * ($new_h / $this->image_height);
        $this->imageresize($new_w, $new_h);
    }

    public function imageresize($new_w, $new_h) {
        $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($new_w, $new_h);
        imagecopyresampled($new_image, $this->image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_w, $new_h, $this->image_width, $this->image_height);
        $this->image_width = $new_w;
        $this->image_height = $new_h;
        $this->image = $new_image;
    }

    public function imagesave($image_type='jpeg', $image_file=NULL, $image_compress=100, $image_permiss='') {
        if($image_file==NULL) {
            switch($this->image_type) {
                case 'gif': header("Content-type: image/gif"); break;
                case 'jpeg': header("Content-type: image/jpeg"); break;
                case 'png': header("Content-type: image/png"); break;
            }
        }
        switch($this->image_type) {
            case 'gif': imagegif($this->image, $image_file); break;
            case 'jpeg': imagejpeg($this->image, $image_file, $image_compress); break;
            case 'png': imagepng($this->image, $image_file); break;
        }
        if($image_permiss != '') {
            chmod($image_file, $image_permiss);
        }
    }

    public function imageout() {
        imagedestroy($this->image);
    }

    public function __destruct() {

    }

}
```

#### Пример использование

```
 public function makeImage($image) {

        $width = 200; // Максимальная ширина картинки
        $height = 200; // Максимальная высота картинки
        $new_image = new Picture($image);
        if($new_image->image_width > $width)
            $new_image->imageresizewidth($width);
        if($new_image->image_height > $height)
            $new_image->imageresizeheight($height);

        $new_image->imagesave($new_image->image_type, $image);
        $new_image->imageout();
    }
```

Comment: Боже мой. Ничего не понятно. код не работает ваш...

Comment: Должен работать. Я сам использовал эту класс. Вы сохранили класс? Как вы использоваете?